# Documentation freezing when editing

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-editor

When editing a topic in SO documentation, my browser started freezing at more or less regular intervals:

- I am sure it comes from SO documentation because I do not have any browser extensions and as soon as I close the SO documentation tab, the freezes stops.
- I had the feeling that the more I edited, the more freezes I had, but I am not 100% sure. At the end I would got a 3-4 seconds freeze every sentence I typed so I simply stopped trying...
- I got popup errors from this script: `http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs…ranspiled.en.js?v=4d1eba653fc8:1` (I do not have the full link), maybe it will help resolve the issue.

I have to say that I am under multiple proxys, which may slow down the connection a lot (like it may takes multiple seconds to load very very very simple pages sometimes).

I am using Firefox ESR 38.5.0.

Comment: I've experienced this too Chrome 52.0.2743.82 m

Comment: Had the same issue, it got worse the more I was editing. In the end I had regular freezes up to 20 seconds (in both Firefox and Chrome).. I think it's related to the preview rendering, since it only happened after I changed something.

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess, the whole topic is re-rendered even if you edit only a section.

Comment: Same here. On latest FF and Chrome in Ubuntu. Up to the extent that I wrote my texts offsite and then pasted them in instead. Super annoying and huge barrier to contributing.

Comment: same here with Chrome 52, tried clearing all site data and logging in again, no joy.

Comment: Same for me. It starts out just fine, but when I edit anything for a while the editor starts freezing, the longer the edit takes the worse and worse it gets. It makes bigger edits unbearable. I can confirm that it has to be something about the editor. Every other website, even other pages on Documentation or Stack Overflow work just fine while this one tab keeps freezing every 3 seconds for about 10 seconds.

Comment: Both Firefox and Chrome. Just copy everything to a text file and edit there.

Comment: I can _never_ make this happen when I actually want to make it happen. ARGH.

Comment: @TimPost Try using a slower computer, and adding about 25,000 characters to an example.  Then, wait for the script to update the "characters added" on the right, add a few more, wait again, and so on; it'll _probably_ start soon, I would guess.  Rather extreme, but it seems to happen more often the more characters you add (usually starts around 6-9k, I believe), so a drastic test like that would be the most likely to cause it.