# Require tag badges for Documentation contributions

Tags: discussion, documentation

To follow up [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329462/contribution-to-documentation-low-engagement-levels-high-approval-turn-aroun) question. The main reason experts don't want to contribute to documentation because at it's current state documentation is flat out *crap*. Not just the UX but also the content itself. It's basically "just in it for the rep" that make small edits to chip in on the reputation gain.

What if we change the documentation contribution requirements to only allow people with a bronze, silver or gold tag badge of that particular tag to edit or create a new topic? This *should* increase the quality of the documentation topics and remove the possibility to edit a lot of different topics with small edits to rep farm but still allows the rep gain from documentation.

Comment: It mirrors the start of SO pretty well, the first year was a pretty useless flood of crap.  It wasn't until about October 2009 before everybody discovered that crap is pointless and experts started to consistently add useful content.  Just about nobody that contributed in the first year is still around, nor is a significant chunk of that crap.  Docs probably needs to evolve like this as well, can't happen in a month.

Comment: @HansPassant Right. But there didn't exist at the time an established and respectable site, of which the naissant SO was being made part of, did there? For Docs it's different. For better or worse (hint:worse), the developers want it to be an integral part of SO. In this case, since SO is now years old, wouldn't it be prudent to use tools, which its evolution has yielded, such as limiting access to metal tags, to prevent Docs from going through the same period of crap? Or should we just let it marinate in the mess it's currently in for a year, just because that's what SO itself went through?

Comment: No real idea what "metal tags" are.  Anybody can post an answer to SO without any restrictions, they don't even need an account.  Maybe you are talking about moderating tools, that took a while to get sorted out at SO as well.  Maybe they'll consider Docs-specific rep to control access to those tools, but that's going to take time since everybody started at 0.  Oops, 1.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I guess I failed to word my comment properly, mostly due to the character limit. By "metal tags" I mean bronze, silver and gold tag badges. And by "limiting access to metal tags" I mean "only allowing users with one of those tag badges to have write access to the Docs for a corresponding tag". I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @HansPassant "Anybody can post an answer to SO without any restrictions." Yes, but the poster will only benefit from doing so if the answer is helpful or useful at least in some way. There is no incentive in the Q&A section to post unnecessary content. There *is* on Docs (see all of the profound 2-3 character [edits](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/revisions/99?exampleId=404) to the "Initializing Arrays" section for Java tag).

Comment: I don't get it, there is no incentive either at Docs to post useless documentation.  Edits don't have anything to do with new posts and edits at SO also earn rep when they are approved.  Envy at earned rep appears to be the primary sticking point here, it is one of the seven deadly sins :)

Comment: @HansPassant: "*It mirrors the start of SO pretty well, the first year was a pretty useless flood of crap.*" There is one big difference. When SO matured, those old questions weren't sitting on the front page. They fall off, replaced by new stuff. Whereas crap documentation is *always there*, always sitting at the top of a topic's documentation. Digging out from under all that will require a Herculean effort to rebuild it, not merely waiting for new docs to push out the old.

Comment: @HansPassant: "*there is no incentive either at Docs to post useless documentation*" Nonsense. If you happen to edit a popular piece of documentation, you will get rep *constantly*, every time it is upvoted. *Forever*. And dismissing it by calling it "envy" when it's a legitimate problem is really not the right attitude to take.

Comment: @HansPassant *"there is no incentive either at Docs to post useless documentation"* Really? *"and edits at SO also earn rep when they are approved"* Yes, but they earn rep **once**. Not every single time someone upvotes the post that was edited. *"Envy at earned rep appears to be the primary sticking point here"* To that I say... so?? Isn't fair distribution of rep (or other virtual currency) an important part of gamifying a system? If it's not done properly it creates perverse incentives, the result of which you can clearly see in the quality of content in Documentation so far.

Comment: If you're making a feature request, maybe tag it as such and explain how it is distinct from http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328978/minimum-tag-score-for-adding-documentation If you want a discussion, well, what new direction are you taking the discussion beyond the one you linked?

Comment: This is definitely a dupe of the question @Frank mentions. It adds nothing aside from specifying what score is required. It would be more appropriate as an answer there, and it has no value there even as other users have already suggested it.

Answer (score 28):

I agree that it would be preferable if only subject matter experts are allowed to contribute to the docs… the whole "*in an ideal world*" and so on.

However, I am not sure limiting by badges is the right way forward.

**Regarding "rep farming":**

I am a member for 5+ years and seen a fair share of gold badgers rep farm, including me. There is no guarantee people will not use docs "for teh reps". Having an entry barrier will obviously lower that amount, even if it just meant that the rich get richer, but it will not prevent it *altogether*. You never claimed that though to be fair.

**Regarding contributions:**

You say

> The main reason experts don't want to contribute to documentation because at it's current state documentation is flat out crap. Not just the UX but also the content itself.

Even if they rebooted the docs, fixed the bugs, UX and structural shortcomings and allowed only badgers to contribute, I cannot be bothered to contribute. **I just don't see utility of that whole project**. I don't see why I should replicate a good portion of my 2602 answers on Q&A over there. It feels wrong. I fought years against duplicates on Q&A and now I am invited to duplicate my stuff there? Why?

As I have pointed elsewhere on MSO, the scope of this docs project is unclear to me. It still is. Replicating my answers cannot be its purpose. Duplicating existing official documentations cannot be its purpose either. And no one needs a bucket of random examples. If you want to contribute a random example, just provide them as self-answered Q&A.

IMO, Docs is competing with Q&A and official documentations for no good reason. The idea to provide docs for otherwise poorly documented projects is laudable, but *The One True SO Documentation* is a wasteful and arrogant effort. Stack Overflow should not attempt to replace an authoritative documentation made by project maintainers elsewhere on the web. I will not participate in that.

The beauty of Stack Overflow for me always was that it gives me quality Q&A *and* links to authoritative outside sources for further digging. As such, it was a peaceful coexistence. I'd like that to continue. I don't want a Stack Overflow silo, where every answer links to some SO.docs instead of official docs. And I don't want the first ten pages of Google SERPs to be to SO only. Diversity is good and needed. SO docs is not.

Comment: `but The One True SO Documentation is a wasteful and arrogant effort.` I couldn't agree more. Currently the "docs" are just a bunch of examples of trivial tasks done in different programming languages.

Comment: "no one needs a bucket of random examples" I think the Docs creators believe that this _is_ exactly What People Need: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329590/ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329544/ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329486/

Comment: @josh these are too wasteful and arrogant examples you just provided

Comment: @NaeemShaikh, sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say. Can you rephrase?

Comment: People just started in believing in SO, for their efforts in solving QnA, thou careers.  They released in SO reps.. docs? And reps they give u? Questionable on how reps can identify u

Comment: @NaeemShaikh: I wouldn't want to work for anyone who would hire a person based on Internet points. People offering jobs through Careers should be looking at the quality of your posts, not your point total. Now, don't take that to mean that I think Docs.SO's rep gain is OK; it's completely ridiculous.

Comment: @nicolas agree.

Comment: "links to authoritative outside sources for further digging." And sadly we are already seeing people link to Docs.SO instead to existing, official, high qualitiy documentation outside the SO silo.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to address another side of things: there are plenty of good ways to contribute to docs without being an expert. Well, two that I've found so far.

**Versioning**. While being an expert might help, *anyone* can go out, find the information, and format it in a table. The version chart needs to be in place before version comments work elsewhere, so it's important to have.

**Plagiarism Detection.** Indisputably, we don't want plagiarism. I have been looking through suggestions and running them through plagiarism checkers (although I'm not too impressed with these tools, so I might start doing it by hand) and rejecting any I catch as copied. You do not need to be a programmer at all to do this (English teachers would have an advantage, though).

Answer (score 4):

I know for myself, I don't have a tag badge in anything (Currently working towards Java and IntelliJ IDEA), but am looking to contribute documentation in those areas, and also topics such as Android.

I will admit I am motivated by the rep, but it is nice to see what I can share with the community.

I think docs would benefit from more "experienced" users, but I think tag badges are maybe a bit too high of a bar to clear. What if a user just started using a new technology, found a tutorial/something in the official docs, and wanted to share it? They wouldn't be able to.

I think (and I admit this is quite vague and ambiguous) that the bar to clear should be an **overall positive question score**, maybe even required to have a few positive-scoring answers in the tag. This would open up to at least knowledgeable users, who don't need to get the 100 score necessary to contribute to docs

Answer (score -15):

Hypothetical:

I rarely post Stackoverflow answers, because I believe it's the "just in it for the rep users" diving on the questions. And because of that I won't get Bronze/Silver/Gold badges. So now only they can edit documentation.

Something you explicitly want to avoid?

Comment: As someone with a gold badge I'm offended that you consider me that type of user. I couldn't care less about rep (or this "documentation" business).

Comment: How dare you answer questions correctly and with suitable information @Roland. Shame! Shame! Shame!

Comment: You need to steer clear of the easy questions with obvious answers. Those are the ones they answer. You can get badges by providing high-quality answers to difficult problems, ones that everyone's dog doesn't already know the answer to.

Comment: @bluefeet Please do not edit my comments. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281749/203914

Comment: @Roland moderators and SE employees have full right to use their moderation tools. You don't like it? Don't use the site, it's simple as that. Just my opinion here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you for the suggestion. I will consider it.